# ¿ Cuando uso [value] y/o [ngValue] o cuando no?

Tags: angular

Trabajo con angular ya hace unos años y he utilizado las dos **`[value]`** y **`[ngValue]`** y comprendo su funcionamiento - En **`[value]:`** solo puedo enviar un valor en especifico mientras que en **`[ngValue]:`** puedo enviar un objeto completo pero me genera un poco de confusión en que momento debo de utilizar uno y el otro ya que con los dos puedo llegar a obtener el dato.

un ejemplo seria al cargar digamos un **select** cual es la mejor opción a utilizar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente lo que comentas es la única diferencia:

- `[value] = "..."` Sólo admite un `string`
- `[ngValue] = "..."` Admite objetos.

Trabajando con HTML estándar (por llamarlo de algún modo), si tuvieras una lista de elementos como

```
const países = [
 {"id":1,"code":"DE","es":"Alemania","locale":"en"}, 
 {"id":2,"code":"AD","es":"Andorra","locale":"es"}, 
 {"id":3,"code":"AR","es":"Argentina","locale":"es"},
 ...
]
```

necesitarías crear con las opciones

```
<option value="1">Alemania</option>
<option value="2">Andorra</option>
<option value="3">Argentina</option>
...
```

Y cuando el usuario elija uno, tendrías que recorrer tu lista de países buscando el que que corresponde:

```
const elegido = paises.find(p=> p.id===valor);
```

Angular hace ese trabajo por ti y simplemente asigna el objeto entero a cada opción, con lo que te ahorras esa búsqueda:

```
//Muestra el nombre del país
console.log('Ha elegido el país', form.controls.pais.getValue().name);
```

Comment: Según lo que comentas entonces es mejor utilizar **`[ngValue]`** para cargar un **select** ya que envía el objeto completo y puedo acceder a cualquier propiedad ?

Comment: Correcto. Yo siempre uso formularios reactivos y ngValue en mi código porque creo que da mucha más flexibilidad y te permite hacer las cosas sin restringirte a los límites tradicionales del HTML/JS en las aplicaciones web

Comment: Gracias tendré que cambiar todos los **[value]** que tengo.